# Google oauth API: add "allowed origin" programmatically

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

My app registers a subdomain for every new customer. It is also using Google oauth to authenticate users. Which means that for every new subdomain there must be a corresponding "allowed origin/redirect url" record.

I can add it manually in the developer console, but is there a way to do it via an api call?

*This of course wouldn't be a problem if google allowed wildcard urls for origins.*

Comment: I assume that's by design and for good reasons there's no way to add dynamically. What about a central redirect URL which then switches to the customers particular redirect? You may add the customer name/id in the `state` parameter.

Comment: You're probably right, there are good reasons not to do that. I just wanted to rule out me missing some docs in case it was actually possible.